# Button counter changing styling

Tags: jquery

Live View: https://tornhq.com/WorkingOn/InteractiveMap/implementing.html 
*- Click on the #Current tab or one of the countries at the bottom*

The current counter, of which works for going up on click of the link is:

```
$(this).text(Number($(this).text()) + 1);
```

I have tried quite a few things, of which I thought this would be the answer:

```
$(this).attr('p').text(Number($(this).attr('p').text()) + 1);
// OR
$(this).html(p).text(Number($(this).html(p).text()) + 1);
```

How can I keep the button counter from going up but keep my styling assigned for the `<p>`?

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: I've just re-phrased the last section "How can I keep the button counter from going up but keep my styling assigned for the <p>?" Upon clicking on my buttron, the styling removes but the counter does go up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see the red counter goes up :

try this

if `this` is your `P` so : 
`$(this).text(function (i,n){return parseInt(n)+1;})`

if `this` is your `a` so :

```
$('p',$(this)).text(function (i,n){return parseInt(n)+1;}) //I think you need this
```

for testing in console the *MATH* part only :

`$("#Like-Earth p").text(function (i,n){return parseInt(n)+1;})`

where `$("#Like-Earth p")` should be changed to 1 of my first options above.

Comment: This is a global function for all my buttons, I need it to be $(this) p.

Comment: "$('p',$(this)).text(function (i,n){return parseInt(n)+1;})" works a charm! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what your attempting to do is replace the current number in the  tag with it incremented by one.

```
var p = jQuery(this).find('p');
var newValue = ParseInt(p.html()) + 1;
jQuery(p).html(newValue);
```

I broke it out int variables but you could combine it into a single long line of code if you wanted as well.